# cannot urlencode() after storing QueryDict in session

Tags: django, django-sessions

I tried to post this to django-users group ( http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/8572d7f4075cfe0e ) but got no responses. Maybe here I will get more help.

I store `request.GET` in session:

```
request.session['query_string'] = request.GET
```

then I retrieve the value in another page and try to urlencode the
QueryDict:

```
context['query_string'] = request.session['query_string'].urlencode()
```

in my context I get the python's string representation of the
QueryDict object instead of the expected `key0=value0&key1=value1&...`
string.

If, instead of QueryDict, I store the urlencoded string in the
session, everything works of course:

```
request.session['query_string'] = request.GET.urlencode()
```

is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is very old, but as I stumbled myself because of the same issue, I want to offer a solution for those reaching this question via a search. The core issue is the [default serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-serializer) Django uses for the session data: `django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer`. This serializer is not aware of keys associated with multiple values (for them, the `getlist()` method of `QueryDict` should be used), which results in only the last value for each key being used.

There are two possible solutions:

- Either manually pickle & unpickle the `request.GET` or `request.POST` object when storing & retrieving from a session;

  - This will call the `__getstate__()` method of `QueryDict`, see also an [old Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10184).
- Or, pickle the whole data of the session, by switching to the `django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer`.

Comment: Another solution when trying to store QueryDict data in session; convert the QueryDict to a dict of lists: `session["foo"] = dict(request.POST.lists())`.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a bug. If you take a peek at the `QueryDict` definition (see [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py)), it says explicitly that it's immutable unless you create a copy of it.

To demonstrate this, here's what I have in my Python shell,

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q1 = QueryDict('', mutable=False)
>>> q2 = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
>>> q1['next'] = '/a&b/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kenny/Desktop/Kreybits/locker/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 357, in __setitem__
    self._assert_mutable()
  File "/Users/kenny/Desktop/Kreybits/locker/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 354, in _assert_mutable
    raise AttributeError("This QueryDict instance is immutable")
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
>>> q2['next'] = '/a&b/'
>>> q2.urlencode()
'next=%2Fa%26b%2F'
```

The `mutable` argument is set to False by default, and since `request.session['query_string'] = request.GET` initialized it to an empty QueryDict to begin with, calling `urlencode()` only returns you an empty str while the `request.session['query_string'] = request.GET.urlencode()` works because you're working with a QueryDict that has been initialized with the appropriate key/values.

Comment: thanks. urlencode() does not return the empty string when called on the object that I get from a session, it returns something like <QueryDict: {u'param0': [u"'a'"], u'param1': [u"'b'"]}> when I expect 'param0=a&param1=b', so my guess is that it is not related to its being immutable.